# Sanding a mildewed deck

Tags: deck

Rented a cabin for vacation use for a year.  It has a covered back deck that was power washed, not allowed to dry in December by landlord and then "sealed" with awful Thompson's.  Smell is awful and would like to sand it down and reseal with Ready Seal. Deck doesn't get any sun.
Suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: for mildew removal portion this is related answer: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/40961/advice-needed-on-staining-10-year-old-fence

Answer (score 1):

Power wash it first, with plain water. Then use a belt sander with a 60grit paper, when the stain/sealer is off sand with a 150grit paper, when done get as much air circulation as you on the deck, open windows and fans.

Comment: I believe the OP was talking about it being covered, not enclosed, so the opening windows is probably not relevant. Fans it good though.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like time for a chemical wash a caustic or acid wash depending on local codes. If the wood was properly treated and then sealed there would be no problems, I used to use Thompsons for many years, it works if prep work is done right it will work. if not. Prepped right nothing will work and may make things worse.